# Rewrite rule. .htaccess . ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, rule

I added the following Rewrite rule to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/?$ index.php?cat=123 [L]
```

and it loads content of /index.php?cat=123 when I go to www.site.com/page

The problem is that I also need to set up redirection from www.site.com/index.php?cat=123 to www.site.com/page
but when I try to do this I get "too many redirections" error. Any idead how fix this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/?$ index.php?cat=123 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=123$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/page [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're saying that you want `index.php` to handle requests for `^page/?` and that `index.php` should redirect to `/page` - that's a circular reference. Without talking about the solution, what's the problem you're trying to solve?